# FFmpegFrameGrabber start() fails

Tags: android, javacv

I am trying to build an app which can process videos from disk. The JavaCV libraries provided the necessary tools for grabbing frames. For some reason, my program crashes when FrameGrabber.start() is invoked.

I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong, I'm new android programming. I've searched for similar cases. Haven't found one posted on the web yet which is similar to mine.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

This is the code I've implemented.

```js
package test.trackerproto;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.util.Log;

import com.googlecode.javacv.FFmpegFrameGrabber;
import com.googlecode.javacv.Frame;

public class Saved_process extends ActionBarActivity {
 
 String FilePath;
 
 
 
 @Override
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
  // TODO Auto-generated method stub
  super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
  setContentView(R.layout.activity_ffile);
  
//  VideoView display = (VideoView)findViewById(R.id.videoView1);
  
  Intent intent = getIntent();
  FilePath = intent.getStringExtra("path");
     FFmpegFrameGrabber vidcap;
//     display.setVideoPath(FilePath);
     vidcap = new FFmpegFrameGrabber(this.FilePath);
     Log.i(camera.TAG, "Framegrab initiated");
        
     Frame cur_frame = null;

     try 
     {
         vidcap.setFormat("mp4");
         Log.i(camera.TAG, "Frame set");
         vidcap.start();    
     } catch (com.googlecode.javacv.FrameGrabber.Exception e) 
     {           
         Log.e(camera.TAG, "Failed to start grabber" + e);     
     }
  
     do
     {
         try
         {
             cur_frame = vidcap.grabFrame();
             if(cur_frame != null){
              Log.i(camera.TAG, "grab success");
             }
                 
         } catch (com.googlecode.javacv.FrameGrabber.Exception e) 
         {
             Log.e(camera.TAG, "video grabFrame failed: "+ e);
         }
     }while(cur_frame != null);

     try 
     {
         vidcap.stop();
     }catch (com.googlecode.javacv.FrameGrabber.Exception e) 
     {
         Log.e(camera.TAG, "failed to stop video grabber", e);
         return;
     }
     
 }
}
```

I've got no compile errors, when start() is invoked it fails, as the last log.i is "frame set"

```html
05-04 15:02:35.022: I/Tracker(20898): Frame set
05-04 15:02:35.078: D/dalvikvm(20898): Trying to load lib /data/app-lib/test.trackerproto-2/libjniavutil.so 0x42308da0
05-04 15:02:35.079: D/dalvikvm(20898): Added shared lib /data/app-lib/test.trackerproto-2/libjniavutil.so 0x42308da0
05-04 15:02:35.541: W/dalvikvm(20898): VFY: unable to find class referenced in signature (Ljava/awt/image/BufferedImage;)
05-04 15:02:35.541: W/dalvikvm(20898): VFY: unable to find class referenced in signature (Ljava/awt/image/BufferedImage;)
05-04 15:02:35.542: W/dalvikvm(20898): VFY: unable to find class referenced in signature (Ljava/awt/image/BufferedImage;)
05-04 15:02:35.542: W/dalvikvm(20898): VFY: unable to find class referenced in signature (Ljava/awt/image/BufferedImage;)
05-04 15:02:35.542: W/dalvikvm(20898): VFY: unable to find class referenced in signature (Ljava/awt/image/BufferedImage;)
05-04 15:02:35.543: I/dalvikvm(20898): Could not find method java.awt.image.BufferedImage.getSampleModel, referenced from method com.googlecode.javacv.cpp.opencv_core$IplImage.createFrom
05-04 15:02:35.543: W/dalvikvm(20898): VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 28530: Ljava/awt/image/BufferedImage;.getSampleModel ()Ljava/awt/image/SampleModel;
05-04 15:02:35.543: D/dalvikvm(20898): VFY: replacing opcode 0x6e at 0x0004
05-04 15:02:35.544: W/dalvikvm(20898): VFY: unable to find class referenced in signature (Ljava/awt/image/BufferedImage;)
05-04 15:02:35.554: W/dalvikvm(20898): VFY: unable to find class referenced in signature (Ljava/awt/image/BufferedImage;)
05-04 15:02:35.566: W/dalvikvm(20898): VFY: unable to find class referenced in signature (Ljava/awt/image/BufferedImage;)
05-04 15:02:35.569: E/dalvikvm(20898): Could not find class 'java.awt.image.BufferedImage', referenced from method com.googlecode.javacv.cpp.opencv_core$IplImage.cloneBufferedImage
05-04 15:02:35.569: W/dalvikvm(20898): VFY: unable to resolve check-cast 2557 (Ljava/awt/image/BufferedImage;) in Lcom/googlecode/javacv/cpp/opencv_core$IplImage;
05-04 15:02:35.569: D/dalvikvm(20898): VFY: replacing opcode 0x1f at 0x0008
05-04 15:02:35.570: W/dalvikvm(20898): VFY: unable to find class referenced in signature (Ljava/awt/image/BufferedImage;)
05-04 15:02:35.570: W/dalvikvm(20898): VFY: unable to find class referenced in signature (Ljava/awt/image/BufferedImage;)
05-04 15:02:35.571: W/dalvikvm(20898): VFY: unable to find class referenced in signature (Ljava/awt/image/BufferedImage;)
05-04 15:02:35.571: W/dalvikvm(20898): VFY: unable to find class referenced in signature (Ljava/awt/image/BufferedImage;)
05-04 15:02:35.571: W/dalvikvm(20898): VFY: unable to find class referenced in signature (Ljava/awt/image/BufferedImage;)
05-04 15:02:35.572: E/dalvikvm(20898): Could not find class 'java.awt.Rectangle', referenced from method com.googlecode.javacv.cpp.opencv_core$IplImage.copyFrom
05-04 15:02:35.572: W/dalvikvm(20898): VFY: unable to resolve new-instance 2546 (Ljava/awt/Rectangle;) in Lcom/googlecode/javacv/cpp/opencv_core$IplImage;
05-04 15:02:35.572: D/dalvikvm(20898): VFY: replacing opcode 0x22 at 0x0007
05-04 15:02:35.573: W/dalvikvm(20898): VFY: unable to find class referenced in signature (Ljava/awt/image/BufferedImage;)
05-04 15:02:35.573: W/dalvikvm(20898): VFY: unable to find class referenced in signature (Ljava/awt/Rectangle;)
05-04 15:02:35.574: W/dalvikvm(20898): VFY: unable to find class referenced in signature (Ljava/awt/image/BufferedImage;)
05-04 15:02:35.574: W/dalvikvm(20898): VFY: unable to find class referenced in signature (Ljava/awt/Rectangle;)
05-04 15:02:35.576: I/dalvikvm(20898): Could not find method java.awt.image.BufferedImage.getSampleModel, referenced from method com.googlecode.javacv.cpp.opencv_core$IplImage.copyFrom
05-04 15:02:35.578: W/dalvikvm(20898): VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 28530: Ljava/awt/image/BufferedImage;.getSampleModel ()Ljava/awt/image/SampleModel;
05-04 15:02:35.578: D/dalvikvm(20898): VFY: replacing opcode 0x74 at 0x000f
05-04 15:02:35.579: W/dalvikvm(20898): VFY: unable to resolve instance field 9196
05-04 15:02:35.579: D/dalvikvm(20898): VFY: replacing opcode 0x52 at 0x009a
05-04 15:02:35.580: W/dalvikvm(20898): VFY: unable to find class referenced in signature (Ljava/awt/image/BufferedImage;)
05-04 15:02:35.581: W/dalvikvm(20898): VFY: unable to find class referenced in signature (Ljava/awt/image/BufferedImage;)
05-04 15:02:35.583: W/dalvikvm(20898): VFY: unable to find class referenced in signature (Ljava/awt/image/BufferedImage;)
05-04 15:02:35.583: W/dalvikvm(20898): VFY: unable to find class referenced in signature (Ljava/awt/image/BufferedImage;)
05-04 15:02:35.584: W/dalvikvm(20898): VFY: unable to find class referenced in signature (Ljava/awt/image/BufferedImage;)
05-04 15:02:35.588: E/dalvikvm(20898): Could not find class 'java.awt.Rectangle', referenced from method com.googlecode.javacv.cpp.opencv_core$IplImage.copyTo
05-04 15:02:35.588: W/dalvikvm(20898): VFY: unable to resolve new-instance 2546 (Ljava/awt/Rectangle;) in Lcom/googlecode/javacv/cpp/opencv_core$IplImage;
05-04 15:02:35.588: D/dalvikvm(20898): VFY: replacing opcode 0x22 at 0x0007
05-04 15:02:35.588: W/dalvikvm(20898): VFY: unable to find class referenced in signature (Ljava/awt/image/BufferedImage;)
05-04 15:02:35.589: W/dalvikvm(20898): VFY: unable to find class referenced in signature (Ljava/awt/Rectangle;)
05-04 15:02:35.591: W/dalvikvm(20898): VFY: unable to find class referenced in signature (Ljava/awt/image/BufferedImage;)
05-04 15:02:35.592: W/dalvikvm(20898): VFY: unable to find class referenced in signature (Ljava/awt/Rectangle;)
05-04 15:02:35.592: I/dalvikvm(20898): Could not find method java.awt.image.BufferedImage.getSampleModel, referenced from method com.googlecode.javacv.cpp.opencv_core$IplImage.copyTo
05-04 15:02:35.593: W/dalvikvm(20898): VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 28530: Ljava/awt/image/BufferedImage;.getSampleModel ()Ljava/awt/image/SampleModel;
05-04 15:02:35.593: D/dalvikvm(20898): VFY: replacing opcode 0x74 at 0x0011
05-04 15:02:35.598: W/dalvikvm(20898): VFY: unable to resolve instance field 9196
05-04 15:02:35.598: D/dalvikvm(20898): VFY: replacing opcode 0x52 at 0x007b
05-04 15:02:35.599: W/dalvikvm(20898): VFY: unable to find class referenced in signature (Ljava/awt/image/BufferedImage;)
05-04 15:02:35.600: W/dalvikvm(20898): VFY: unable to find class referenced in signature (Ljava/awt/image/BufferedImage;)
05-04 15:02:35.602: W/dalvikvm(20898): VFY: unable to find class referenced in signature (Ljava/awt/image/BufferedImage;)
05-04 15:02:35.606: W/dalvikvm(20898): VFY: unable to find class referenced in signature (Ljava/awt/image/BufferedImage;)
05-04 15:02:35.606: W/dalvikvm(20898): VFY: unable to find class referenced in signature (Ljava/awt/color/ColorSpace;)
05-04 15:02:35.616: W/dalvikvm(20898): VFY: unable to find class referenced in signature (Ljava/awt/image/BufferedImage;)
05-04 15:02:35.618: W/dalvikvm(20898): VFY: unable to find class referenced in signature (Ljava/awt/image/BufferedImage;)
05-04 15:02:35.619: W/dalvikvm(20898): VFY: unable to find class referenced in signature (Ljava/awt/color/ColorSpace;)
05-04 15:02:35.621: E/dalvikvm(20898): Could not find class 'java.awt.image.BufferedImage', referenced from method com.googlecode.javacv.cpp.opencv_core$IplImage.getBufferedImage
05-04 15:02:35.621: W/dalvikvm(20898): VFY: unable to resolve new-instance 2557 (Ljava/awt/image/BufferedImage;) in Lcom/googlecode/javacv/cpp/opencv_core$IplImage;
05-04 15:02:35.621: D/dalvikvm(20898): VFY: replacing opcode 0x22 at 0x000e
05-04 15:02:35.622: I/dalvikvm(20898): Could not find method java.awt.color.ColorSpace.getInstance, referenced from method com.googlecode.javacv.cpp.opencv_core$IplImage.getBufferedImage
05-04 15:02:35.622: W/dalvikvm(20898): VFY: unable to resolve static method 28511: Ljava/awt/color/ColorSpace;.getInstance (I)Ljava/awt/color/ColorSpace;
05-04 15:02:35.622: D/dalvikvm(20898): VFY: replacing opcode 0x71 at 0x0033
05-04 15:02:35.627: E/dalvikvm(20898): Could not find class 'java.awt.image.ComponentColorModel', referenced from method com.googlecode.javacv.cpp.opencv_core$IplImage.getBufferedImage
05-04 15:02:35.627: W/dalvikvm(20898): VFY: unable to resolve new-instance 2559 (Ljava/awt/image/ComponentColorModel;) in Lcom/googlecode/javacv/cpp/opencv_core$IplImage;
05-04 15:02:35.627: D/dalvikvm(20898): VFY: replacing opcode 0x22 at 0x0052
05-04 15:02:35.629: E/dalvikvm(20898): Could not find class 'java.awt.image.BufferedImage', referenced from method com.googlecode.javacv.cpp.opencv_core$IplImage.getBufferedImage
05-04 15:02:35.629: W/dalvikvm(20898): VFY: unable to resolve check-cast 2557 (Ljava/awt/image/BufferedImage;) in Lcom/googlecode/javacv/cpp/opencv_core$IplImage;
05-04 15:02:35.629: D/dalvikvm(20898): VFY: replacing opcode 0x1f at 0x0094
05-04 15:02:35.632: E/dalvikvm(20898): Could not find class 'java.awt.image.BufferedImage', referenced from method com.googlecode.javacv.cpp.opencv_core$IplImage.getBufferedImage
05-04 15:02:35.632: W/dalvikvm(20898): VFY: unable to resolve check-cast 2557 (Ljava/awt/image/BufferedImage;) in Lcom/googlecode/javacv/cpp/opencv_core$IplImage;
05-04 15:02:35.632: D/dalvikvm(20898): VFY: replacing opcode 0x1f at 0x00b7
05-04 15:02:35.635: I/dalvikvm(20898): Could not find method java.awt.color.ColorSpace.getInstance, referenced from method com.googlecode.javacv.cpp.opencv_core$IplImage.getBufferedImage
05-04 15:02:35.635: W/dalvikvm(20898): VFY: unable to resolve static method 28511: Ljava/awt/color/ColorSpace;.getInstance (I)Ljava/awt/color/ColorSpace;
05-04 15:02:35.635: D/dalvikvm(20898): VFY: replacing opcode 0x71 at 0x00c6
05-04 15:02:35.637: I/dalvikvm(20898): Could not find method java.awt.color.ColorSpace.getInstance, referenced from method com.googlecode.javacv.cpp.opencv_core$IplImage.getBufferedImage
05-04 15:02:35.637: W/dalvikvm(20898): VFY: unable to resolve static method 28511: Ljava/awt/color/ColorSpace;.getInstance (I)Ljava/awt/color/ColorSpace;
05-04 15:02:35.637: D/dalvikvm(20898): VFY: replacing opcode 0x71 at 0x00de
05-04 15:02:35.638: E/dalvikvm(20898): Could not find class 'java.awt.image.ComponentColorModel', referenced from method com.googlecode.javacv.cpp.opencv_core$IplImage.getBufferedImage
05-04 15:02:35.638: W/dalvikvm(20898): VFY: unable to resolve new-instance 2559 (Ljava/awt/image/ComponentColorModel;) in Lcom/googlecode/javacv/cpp/opencv_core$IplImage;
05-04 15:02:35.638: D/dalvikvm(20898): VFY: replacing opcode 0x22 at 0x00fc
05-04 15:02:35.639: E/dalvikvm(20898): Could not find class 'java.awt.image.ComponentColorModel', referenced from method com.googlecode.javacv.cpp.opencv_core$IplImage.getBufferedImage
05-04 15:02:35.639: W/dalvikvm(20898): VFY: unable to resolve new-instance 2559 (Ljava/awt/image/ComponentColorModel;) in Lcom/googlecode/javacv/cpp/opencv_core$IplImage;
05-04 15:02:35.639: D/dalvikvm(20898): VFY: replacing opcode 0x22 at 0x012e
05-04 15:02:35.640: E/dalvikvm(20898): Could not find class 'java.awt.image.ComponentColorModel', referenced from method com.googlecode.javacv.cpp.opencv_core$IplImage.getBufferedImage
05-04 15:02:35.640: W/dalvikvm(20898): VFY: unable to resolve new-instance 2559 (Ljava/awt/image/ComponentColorModel;) in Lcom/googlecode/javacv/cpp/opencv_core$IplImage;
05-04 15:02:35.640: D/dalvikvm(20898): VFY: replacing opcode 0x22 at 0x0160
05-04 15:02:35.641: E/dalvikvm(20898): Could not find class 'java.awt.image.ComponentColorModel', referenced from method com.googlecode.javacv.cpp.opencv_core$IplImage.getBufferedImage
05-04 15:02:35.641: W/dalvikvm(20898): VFY: unable to resolve new-instance 2559 (Ljava/awt/image/ComponentColorModel;) in Lcom/googlecode/javacv/cpp/opencv_core$IplImage;
05-04 15:02:35.641: D/dalvikvm(20898): VFY: replacing opcode 0x22 at 0x0191
05-04 15:02:35.644: E/dalvikvm(20898): Could not find class 'java.awt.image.ComponentColorModel', referenced from method com.googlecode.javacv.cpp.opencv_core$IplImage.getBufferedImage
05-04 15:02:35.644: W/dalvikvm(20898): VFY: unable to resolve new-instance 2559 (Ljava/awt/image/ComponentColorModel;) in Lcom/googlecode/javacv/cpp/opencv_core$IplImage;
05-04 15:02:35.644: D/dalvikvm(20898): VFY: replacing opcode 0x22 at 0x01c2
05-04 15:02:35.645: E/dalvikvm(20898): Could not find class 'java.awt.image.BufferedImage', referenced from method com.googlecode.javacv.cpp.opencv_core$IplImage.getBufferedImage
05-04 15:02:35.645: W/dalvikvm(20898): VFY: unable to resolve check-cast 2557 (Ljava/awt/image/BufferedImage;) in Lcom/googlecode/javacv/cpp/opencv_core$IplImage;
05-04 15:02:35.645: D/dalvikvm(20898): VFY: replacing opcode 0x1f at 0x01f9
05-04 15:02:35.646: E/dalvikvm(20898): Could not find class 'java.awt.image.BufferedImage', referenced from method com.googlecode.javacv.cpp.opencv_core$IplImage.getBufferedImage
05-04 15:02:35.646: W/dalvikvm(20898): VFY: unable to resolve new-instance 2557 (Ljava/awt/image/BufferedImage;) in Lcom/googlecode/javacv/cpp/opencv_core$IplImage;
05-04 15:02:35.646: D/dalvikvm(20898): VFY: replacing opcode 0x22 at 0x0077
05-04 15:02:35.649: D/dalvikvm(20898): DexOpt: unable to opt direct call 0x6f6b at 0x1e in Lcom/googlecode/javacv/cpp/opencv_core$IplImage;.cloneBufferedImage
05-04 15:02:35.651: D/dalvikvm(20898): DexOpt: unable to opt direct call 0x6f6a at 0x2d in Lcom/googlecode/javacv/cpp/opencv_core$IplImage;.cloneBufferedImage
05-04 15:02:35.658: D/dalvikvm(20898): DexOpt: unable to opt direct call 0x6f5e at 0x19 in Lcom/googlecode/javacv/cpp/opencv_core$IplImage;.copyFrom
05-04 15:02:35.659: I/dalvikvm(20898): DexOpt: unable to optimize instance field ref 0x23eb at 0xa3 in Lcom/googlecode/javacv/cpp/opencv_core$IplImage;.copyFrom
05-04 15:02:35.661: D/dalvikvm(20898): DexOpt: unable to opt direct call 0x6f5e at 0x19 in Lcom/googlecode/javacv/cpp/opencv_core$IplImage;.copyTo
05-04 15:02:35.661: I/dalvikvm(20898): DexOpt: unable to optimize instance field ref 0x23eb at 0x84 in Lcom/googlecode/javacv/cpp/opencv_core$IplImage;.copyTo
05-04 15:02:35.662: D/dalvikvm(20898): DexOpt: unable to opt direct call 0x6f6a at 0x18 in Lcom/googlecode/javacv/cpp/opencv_core$IplImage;.getBufferedImage
05-04 15:02:35.662: D/dalvikvm(20898): DexOpt: unable to opt direct call 0x6f78 at 0x59 in Lcom/googlecode/javacv/cpp/opencv_core$IplImage;.getBufferedImage
05-04 15:02:35.662: D/dalvikvm(20898): DexOpt: unable to opt direct call 0x6f79 at 0x6f in Lcom/googlecode/javacv/cpp/opencv_core$IplImage;.getBufferedImage
05-04 15:02:35.663: D/dalvikvm(20898): DexOpt: unable to opt direct call 0x6f6b at 0x7d in Lcom/googlecode/javacv/cpp/opencv_core$IplImage;.getBufferedImage
05-04 15:02:35.663: D/dalvikvm(20898): DexOpt: unable to opt direct call 0x6f78 at 0x103 in Lcom/googlecode/javacv/cpp/opencv_core$IplImage;.getBufferedImage
05-04 15:02:35.664: D/dalvikvm(20898): DexOpt: unable to opt direct call 0x6f79 at 0x11b in Lcom/googlecode/javacv/cpp/opencv_core$IplImage;.getBufferedImage
05-04 15:02:35.666: D/dalvikvm(20898): DexOpt: unable to opt direct call 0x6f78 at 0x135 in Lcom/googlecode/javacv/cpp/opencv_core$IplImage;.getBufferedImage
05-04 15:02:35.667: D/dalvikvm(20898): DexOpt: unable to opt direct call 0x6f79 at 0x14d in Lcom/googlecode/javacv/cpp/opencv_core$IplImage;.getBufferedImage
05-04 15:02:35.668: D/dalvikvm(20898): DexOpt: unable to opt direct call 0x6f78 at 0x167 in Lcom/googlecode/javacv/cpp/opencv_core$IplImage;.getBufferedImage
05-04 15:02:35.672: D/dalvikvm(20898): DexOpt: unable to opt direct call 0x6f79 at 0x17f in Lcom/googlecode/javacv/cpp/opencv_core$IplImage;.getBufferedImage
05-04 15:02:35.675: D/dalvikvm(20898): DexOpt: unable to opt direct call 0x6f78 at 0x198 in Lcom/googlecode/javacv/cpp/opencv_core$IplImage;.getBufferedImage
05-04 15:02:35.677: D/dalvikvm(20898): DexOpt: unable to opt direct call 0x6f79 at 0x1b0 in Lcom/googlecode/javacv/cpp/opencv_core$IplImage;.getBufferedImage
05-04 15:02:35.678: D/dalvikvm(20898): DexOpt: unable to opt direct call 0x6f78 at 0x1c9 in Lcom/googlecode/javacv/cpp/opencv_core$IplImage;.getBufferedImage
05-04 15:02:35.678: D/dalvikvm(20898): DexOpt: unable to opt direct call 0x6f79 at 0x1e1 in Lcom/googlecode/javacv/cpp/opencv_core$IplImage;.getBufferedImage
05-04 15:02:35.707: D/dalvikvm(20898): Trying to load lib /data/app-lib/test.trackerproto-2/libtbb.so 0x42308da0
05-04 15:02:35.731: D/dalvikvm(20898): Added shared lib /data/app-lib/test.trackerproto-2/libtbb.so 0x42308da0
05-04 15:02:35.731: D/dalvikvm(20898): No JNI_OnLoad found in /data/app-lib/test.trackerproto-2/libtbb.so 0x42308da0, skipping init
05-04 15:02:35.753: D/dalvikvm(20898): Trying to load lib /data/app-lib/test.trackerproto-2/libjniopencv_core.so 0x42308da0
05-04 15:02:35.762: E/dalvikvm(20898): dlopen("/data/app-lib/test.trackerproto-2/libjniopencv_core.so") failed: dlopen failed: could not load library "libopencv_core.so" needed by "libjniopencv_core.so"; caused by library "libopencv_core.so" not found
05-04 15:02:35.763: W/dalvikvm(20898): Exception Ljava/lang/UnsatisfiedLinkError; thrown while initializing Lcom/googlecode/javacv/cpp/opencv_core;
05-04 15:02:35.764: W/dalvikvm(20898): Exception Ljava/lang/NoClassDefFoundError; thrown while initializing Lcom/googlecode/javacv/cpp/opencv_core$CvArr;
05-04 15:02:35.768: D/AndroidRuntime(20898): Shutting down VM
05-04 15:02:35.770: W/dalvikvm(20898): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x41a38d40)
05-04 15:02:35.793: E/AndroidRuntime(20898): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
05-04 15:02:35.793: E/AndroidRuntime(20898): Process: test.trackerproto, PID: 20898
05-04 15:02:35.793: E/AndroidRuntime(20898): java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.googlecode.javacv.cpp.opencv_core
05-04 15:02:35.793: E/AndroidRuntime(20898):  at com.googlecode.javacpp.Loader.load(Loader.java:563)
05-04 15:02:35.793: E/AndroidRuntime(20898):  at com.googlecode.javacpp.Loader.load(Loader.java:540)
05-04 15:02:35.793: E/AndroidRuntime(20898):  at com.googlecode.javacv.cpp.opencv_core$CvArr.<clinit>(opencv_core.java:156)
05-04 15:02:35.793: E/AndroidRuntime(20898):  at com.googlecode.javacv.FFmpegFrameGrabber.startUnsafe(FFmpegFrameGrabber.java:426)
05-04 15:02:35.793: E/AndroidRuntime(20898):  at com.googlecode.javacv.FFmpegFrameGrabber.start(FFmpegFrameGrabber.java:308)
05-04 15:02:35.793: E/AndroidRuntime(20898):  at test.trackerproto.Saved_process.onCreate(Saved_process.java:39)
05-04 15:02:35.793: E/AndroidRuntime(20898):  at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5248)
05-04 15:02:35.793: E/AndroidRuntime(20898):  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1110)
05-04 15:02:35.793: E/AndroidRuntime(20898):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2162)
05-04 15:02:35.793: E/AndroidRuntime(20898):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2257)
05-04 15:02:35.793: E/AndroidRuntime(20898):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:139)
05-04 15:02:35.793: E/AndroidRuntime(20898):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1210)
05-04 15:02:35.793: E/AndroidRuntime(20898):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
05-04 15:02:35.793: E/AndroidRuntime(20898):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
05-04 15:02:35.793: E/AndroidRuntime(20898):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5086)
05-04 15:02:35.793: E/AndroidRuntime(20898):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
05-04 15:02:35.793: E/AndroidRuntime(20898):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
05-04 15:02:35.793: E/AndroidRuntime(20898):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:785)
05-04 15:02:35.793: E/AndroidRuntime(20898):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:601)
05-04 15:02:35.793: E/AndroidRuntime(20898):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
05-04 15:02:35.793: E/AndroidRuntime(20898): Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.googlecode.javacv.cpp.opencv_core
05-04 15:02:35.793: E/AndroidRuntime(20898):  at java.lang.Class.classForName(Native Method)
05-04 15:02:35.793: E/AndroidRuntime(20898):  at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:251)
05-04 15:02:35.793: E/AndroidRuntime(20898):  at com.googlecode.javacpp.Loader.load(Loader.java:561)
05-04 15:02:35.793: E/AndroidRuntime(20898):  ... 19 more
05-04 15:02:35.793: E/AndroidRuntime(20898): Caused by: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: dlopen failed: could not load library "libopencv_core.so" needed by "libjniopencv_core.so"; caused by library "libopencv_core.so" not found
05-04 15:02:35.793: E/AndroidRuntime(20898):  at java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary(Runtime.java:364)
05-04 15:02:35.793: E/AndroidRuntime(20898):  at java.lang.System.loadLibrary(System.java:526)
05-04 15:02:35.793: E/AndroidRuntime(20898):  at com.googlecode.javacpp.Loader.loadLibrary(Loader.java:711)
05-04 15:02:35.793: E/AndroidRuntime(20898):  at com.googlecode.javacpp.Loader.load(Loader.java:586)
05-04 15:02:35.793: E/AndroidRuntime(20898):  at com.googlecode.javacpp.Loader.load(Loader.java:540)
05-04 15:02:35.793: E/AndroidRuntime(20898):  at com.googlecode.javacv.cpp.opencv_core.<clinit>(opencv_core.java:134)
05-04 15:02:35.793: E/AndroidRuntime(20898):  ... 22 more
05-04 15:02:35.793: E/AndroidRuntime(20898): Caused by: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Couldn't load opencv_core from loader dalvik.system.PathClassLoader[DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/test.trackerproto-2.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app-lib/test.trackerproto-2, /vendor/lib, /system/lib]]]: findLibrary returned null
05-04 15:02:35.793: E/AndroidRuntime(20898):  at java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary(Runtime.java:358)
05-04 15:02:35.793: E/AndroidRuntime(20898):  at java.lang.System.loadLibrary(System.java:526)
05-04 15:02:35.793: E/AndroidRuntime(20898):  at com.googlecode.javacpp.Loader.loadLibrary(Loader.java:711)
05-04 15:02:35.793: E/AndroidRuntime(20898):  at com.googlecode.javacpp.Loader.load(Loader.java:577)
05-04 15:02:35.793: E/AndroidRuntime(20898):  ... 24 more
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this problem. The version of javacv used was 0.7 and this version had issues similar to this (from my understanding most versions below 0.10 had a similar issue). The latest version to as of the post date, is 0.11 and using this it solved my problems. I'm leaving this here, if in case it helps someone!

Comment: suggestion, try out to load static lib of ffmpeg - https://github.com/guardianproject/android-ffmpeg

Comment: @Manoj did you just change the javacv.jar file or any other jar /so file. Please reply as I am experiencing the same issue

Comment: One other thing I marked that there was static import of com.googlecode.javacv.cpp.opencv_core.IplImage in older javacv however that class or cpp package not included in javacv-0.11.jar